# Exception when calling FragmentTransaction.Commit()

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am trying to do something that should be simple, my main layout is like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:name="io.raindance.kalimat.grid.GridFragment"
        android:id="@+id/gridControlInMainView" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />        

</LinearLayout>
```

There's no Java code in the main activity; now the GridFragment's code and layout is just like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridFragmentMainContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

</LinearLayout>
```

Java Code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Load the layout of the rack tile
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_fragment, null, false);



    // Get the root linear layout to add the rows to it
        LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.gridFragmentMainContainer);

        // Build the rows of the grid
            int rowsId = 21;
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            // Create the linear layout that represents a row in the grid
            LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(this.getActivity());
            row.setId(rowsId++);
            row.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

            row.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 10, 1.0f));

            // Build the cells of the grid
            for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++) {
                // Create the cell fragment
                CellFragment cellFragment = new CellFragment();
            // Add the cell fragment to the row fragment
                            this.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(row.getId(), cellFragment).commit();
}
        // Add the row to the root element
        root.addView(row);
    }

    return view;
}
```

The CellFragment layout is simply as mentioned below and there's no Java code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/lll1"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</LinearLayout>
```

When I run the application, I get an exception because of the commit() call, cause the exception is not raised when I remove the commit() call and anyway the rows are being successfully created and added to the hierarchy.

I get the below exception
07-08 03:36:27.414: E/AndroidRuntime(835): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{io.raindance.kalimat/io.raindance.kalimat.test.KalimatActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f050005 for fragment CellFragment{4103c790 #1 id=0x7f050005}

I have been looking for the reason and the solution of this problem for 2 days now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Activity` needs to be created (and its state saved) in order for a `FragmentTransaction` to be performed, otherwise you will get an exception. Try performing your transaction in `onActivityCreated` instead.

Comment: Your code also attempts to embed a fragment within a fragment. You shouldn't ever meed to instantiate a new cellfragment and attempt to add it to the parent view. This is probably why you are getting an exception... you cant have a fragment exist within a fragment. You should consider reading up on fragments on the developers site.

Comment: I guess this is it, you can't set fragments inside other fragments, thank you